# Changing the DOCUMENT_ROOT or a better approach

Tags: php, macos, url, path, document-root

Is there a better way to take set the path for my local environment. Here is what i am trying to do

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {
    define("URL", "/mysite");
}else{
    define("URL", "");
}
?>
```

the only problem with this approach is I need to litter my code with stuff like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/css/main-style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>/css/home.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo URL; ?>/js/jquery.js?v=1.5.2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . URL . '/inc/header-inc.php'); ?>
```

And i have to find every absolute path in my site and add the URL in front which is cluttering the code with this. I am on MAc osx and my DOCUMENT_ROOT is /Users/alex/Sites

I can change it to /Users/alex/Sites/mysite but what happens when I need mysite2

Comment: It's your local environment... there's no reason you can't set up multiple hosts on whatever domain(s) you want, each having its own document root.

Comment: hosts file to let your system resolve the names, and then a virtualhost for each site in your httpd.conf.

Comment: do you have a snippet example so i can understand how to set it up locally...

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this [approach](http://www.thermalexposure.com/2010/07/31/host-multiple-subdomains-on-mac-osx-10-6/)

Comment: Sorry, the link is broken.